# Why variables need to be declare but sometimes don't in Python?

Tags: python, variables

I know that Python variables could be used when it first declared like Example 1, but when I try Example 2 without the line `total = 0`, it will appear `NameError: 'name' total is not defined`. Why?

## Example 1

```
dmil = float(input("Enter the distance (miles): "))
dis = dmil * 1.61
print("The distance in miles {} is equal to {} in 
kilometer.".format(dmil,dis))
```

## Example 2

```
total = 0  #why I necessarily need this?
for i in range (1,4):
    h = float(input("Enter the {} height: ".format(i)))
    total = h + total
avg = total/3
print("The average height of the 3 cousins is ",avg)
```

It really confused me when I type programmes, is there a definition about when should I declare var at first and when should not?

Comment: You always have to define the variable before accessing it.

Comment: There are no declarations in Python, only *assignments*.

Answer (score 0):

`total = h + total` is intending to add the value of `h` to what `total` currently is. 
Without having previously stated what `total` currently is, there is no value to add `h`.

In simpler terms, if you remove the `total = 0` statement, walk through the code line-by-line and when you reach `total = h + total`, what should `h + total` be, it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`total = 0` is not a declaration per se: it's an initialization. It is needed because when you get to the line

```
    total = h + total
```

the value of `total` on the RHS would be unknown. Python tries to look up the value and finds nothing by that name at that point in your program, so it complains.

Comment: Everybody complains nowadays.

Comment: Yes, but in this case it is justified :-)